# Fetch multiple records based on multiple email address from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql Database I am trying to get the users ID of 100 people based on their email address. I have the email address for all the users but when I run the query for multiple records it didn't work. For single record its working. I tried below.

```
Select ID 
  from users 
 where email_address IN ("abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com, exs@gmail.com")
```

Also tried this one

```
Select ID 
  from users 
 where email_address = ("abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com, exs@gmail.com")
```

but they didn't work.

For single record its working but I need for multiple record. Can you help me find out where I am wrong.

```
This is for single one

select ID from users where email_address = "abc@gmail.com".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a *single* string to `IN`.  Instead:

```
where email_address IN ('abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@gmail.com', . . . )
```

This is a *list* of strings.

If you are passing the list in as a parameter, you might intend `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(email_address, 'abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,...')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `RLIKE`.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email_address` RLIKE '^(abc@gmail.com|xyz@gmail.com|exs@gmail.com)$';
```